# How to use caching on c#

Tags: c#, caching

I want to use simply with cache on c#

I get an object from DB and i want save it for 30 seconds on the cache ,

so on this 30 seconds i don't need to get again this information from DB.

for example:

```
if(cache("name")== empty)
       MyClass temp=GetFromDb();
        InsertToCache("name")
else
   MyClass temp=selectFromCache("name")
```

I don't find a way to do this .

thanks you all.

Comment: You can take a look at ['MemoryCache'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please specify your post! What type of C#-application?

Comment: @heinzbeinz
i not like to ask a code, but i serached there...
don't know why, but not success
can you please write it for me?

Comment: "can you please write it for me" That's not what this site is for.

Comment: @MrAnderson
i know , i never done it before
just simply not success to do this
if you have 1 min to write, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example similar to what you're trying to accomplish:

```
public Person RetrievePerson(string name)
{
    var memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default; // Needs a reference to System.Runtime.Caching
    var person = memoryCache.Get(name) as Person;

    if (person == null)
    {
        person = CreatePerson(name);

        memoryCache.Add(name, person, new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
        });
    }

    return person;
}
```

Note that you'll need a reference to System.Runtime.Caching (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx for help).

For more information on MemoryCache, CacheItemPolicy, etc. just check out MSDN (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).